# How should I approach copy/pasted homework questions with nothing added?

Tags: discussion

How should I approach questions that are clearly copy/pasted from a homework sheet? The question contains nothing else but the copy/pasted text (with question numbering intact) and a "pls help".

Downvote and comment a link to the How to ask page?